# Wordpress mail gets to spam folder

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress site registration email gets into the spam folder.
My client uses an old version of Microsoft exchange without SMTP support.
so I can't send the mails true SMPT. And my servers Pp is not Blacklisted.

Domain:
cottex.se

SPF on the Domain:
v=spf1 mx a ip4:178.62.70.32 ?all

I have not setup DKIM(DomainKeys Identified Mail) Because I can't find how to sign the WordPress outgoing mail with a private key.

I really can't understand whats wrong! the SPF should be enough or?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend test your mail on this [website](https://www.mail-tester.com/)

It show you details about problems on the your mail domain.
Send message to specified email and click blue button.

Comment: As you can see I get 9/10. The only thing i dont have is "Your message is not signed with DKIM"
https://www.mail-tester.com/web-5823b&reloaded=1

Comment: Which destination mail service accepted your mails. I mean gmail, hotmail etc?

Comment: Hotmail(outlook), Gmail, our own mail server (kerioConnect) and Microsoft exchange

Comment: All of there marked your mails as spam? Try to [setup DKIM](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy) on the your mail server and DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code its help you:-

Note: You need to use valid email and name here.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'my_mail_from' );
function my_mail_from( $email ) {
    return "enter yout 'from' id";
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
function new_mail_from_name($old) {
    return 'enter your "from name"';
}
wp_mail( $admin_mail, $subject, $message );
```

Comment: I already have this 
// Change the default wordpress@ email address

add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'cb_new_mail_from_name');
 
function cb_new_mail_from_name($old) {
return 'Cottex.se';
}



//Mail from 
function xyz_filter_wp_mail_from($email){
return "info@cottex.se";
}
add_filter("wp_mail_from", "xyz_filter_wp_mail_from");